# intercept select all checkbox event on client grid

Tags: telerik, client-side, radgrid

I have a client radgrid with a select column and some other columns. when the select all checkbox is checked it attempts to check all rows in the grid. I didnt want it to select every row unless it obeyed certain conditions so I added some javascript to do this. 
Because it potentially doesnt select all rows, the select all check box wont be selected. I want to check the select all checkbox here so that when it is unchecked, it will remove all the selected rows.
Looking for a way to get the click event of the select all checkbox or something similar. I don't believe there is an OnClick event assoicated with it but i could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

.ASPX

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function SelecteHeaderItemClick(obj) {

            alert('Header Item Checked');


            var grid = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>");
            if (grid) {
                var MasterTable = grid.get_masterTableView();
                var Rows = MasterTable.get_dataItems();
                for (var i = 0; i < Rows.length; i++) {
                    var row = Rows[i];
                    if (parseInt(row.getDataKeyValue('ID')) != 1)
                        row.set_selected($(obj).is(':checked'));
                }
            }
        }
        function SelecteItemClick() {
            alert('Item Checked');
        }
    </script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

.ASPX.CS

```
protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic data = new[] {
        new { ID = 1, Name ="Name1"},
        new { ID = 2, Name = "Name2"},
        new { ID = 3, Name = "Name3"},
         new { ID = 4, Name = "Name4"},
        new { ID = 5, Name = "Name5"}
    };

    RadGrid1.DataSource = data;
}


protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
        (item["SelectColumn"].Controls[0] as CheckBox).Attributes.Add("onclick", "SelecteItemClick();");
    }

    if (e.Item is GridHeaderItem)
    {
        GridHeaderItem item = e.Item as GridHeaderItem;
        (item["SelectColumn"].Controls[0] as CheckBox).Attributes.Add("onclick", "SelecteHeaderItemClick(this);");
    }
}
```